# Display all validation errors in alertbox

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Is it possible to list all validation errors in alertbox. Currently its showing only the first instance of the error.

```
function form_validation_alert(type, name, num){
  name = name.replace(/^\W*(\w*)\W*$/, "$1");
  msg = form_validation_alerts[type];
  msg = msg.replace('%%Name%%', name.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase()+name.substr(1, name.length-1).toLowerCase());
  msg = msg.replace('%%name%%', name.toLowerCase());
  msg = msg.replace('%%num%%', num);

  alert(msg);

  return false;
}
```

JavaScript code: http://catch24.catch24dev.com/forms/form-validation.js

You can check the form at: http://catch24.catch24dev.com/forms

Thanks!

Comment: Post your relevant code here.

Comment: I was not able to put all code, because of StackOverflow restrictions. Source code: http://catch24.catch24dev.com/forms/form-validation.js

Answer (score 0):

try to concatenate all messages.

```
function form_validation_alert(type, name, num){
  name = name.replace(/^\W*(\w*)\W*$/, "$1");
  msg = form_validation_alerts[type];
  msg = msg + msg.replace('%%Name%%', name.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase()+name.substr(1, name.length-1).toLowerCase());
  msg = msg + msg.replace('%%name%%', name.toLowerCase());
  msg = msg + msg.replace('%%num%%', num);

  alert(msg);

  return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to concatenate but it displayed the same strings for several times.